# Changing Src of an Embed Swf Player

Tags: javascript, flash

So I'm working on a little project which has a little over 50 swf movies, and I wanted to be able to watch them like a normal human being (play, pause, rewind and all those good stuff).

Anywho, I've made all that happen..
The only thing I can't seem to get is changing the embed flash player **dynamically**, i.e the user chooses the .swf file to be shown instead of the path being hard-coded.

This is my code so far:

```js
function changePlayerSrc()
{
  var player  = document.getElementById("flash_player_obj"); //selects the flash player object
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]; //get the user's file
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function()
  {
    var clone = player.cloneNode(true); //cloned player
    var res = reader.result; //user's file as blob

    clone.childNodes[1].setAttribute('src', res); //change src
    player.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, player);
  }
  
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```html
<object id = "flash_player_obj">
    <embed = "flash_player_embed" 
        name = "flash_player"
        src = "H:\test.swf"
        width = "100%"
        height = "500"
        play = "false"
        loop = "false"
        quality = "high"
        scale = "showall"
    />
</object>

<input type="file" onchange="changePlayerSrc()" />
```

The above code just gives me a blank flash player with nothing playing.

---

I've also tried using `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);`

```js
var res   = reader.result;
var blob  = new Blob([res], {type: "application/x-shockwave-flash"});
var url   = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

And using the url as src for the embed, this just opens the save file dialog for some reason..

---

Also note that I'm not using any server side code, because there isn't any server to work with.
This script is running solely on a single `.html` file.

Comment: Here's a funny thing..
I tired choosing an img file instead of swf for giggles and it worked..

So apparently the code works, just not for swf files lol.
Anyone has an idea why that is?

Comment: Are you opening the HTML file locally, i.e. just opening the HTML on the browser? If so, you cannot load SWFs from the local file system. You either need to load your HTML from a local web server, or change the security settings of your browser/Flash to allow that.

Comment: Okay, I've tried to use the html through localhost (Used windows IIS for that), still wont let me open a flash :C
Only picture files and stuff like that works, how do i access the security settings panel for flash?